# How do I read just part of a string?

Tags: python

For my program I ask the user to input a command. If the user writes: Input filename (filename being any possible name of a file in the computer) I want my program to only read Input so it knows what if statement to use and then open the file that the user wrote.
There is also another part where I have to do a similar task, where the user inputs: score n goals.(n is the top number of players the program has to read from a list) I want the program to differentiate this from 2 other similar tasks (score n misses and score n passes).

I am not sure if I'm approaching this the correct way, but this was my try for the first case I talked about, but it doesn't work.

```
user_input = input ('File name:')

input_lowered = user_input.lower()

command = input_lowered[0:4]

if command == 'input' :

    fp = open ("soccer.part.txt")

else :

    user_upper = input ('Input name:')
```

Thanks in advance for any clue of how I should aim at fixing this!!!

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: `"Input"[0:4] == "Inpu"`, as you would see if you'd bothered to `print(command)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as follows:

```
your_string[0:5]
```

This will get the first five characters of the string as a string.

Comment: Or just `your_string[:5]`

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to use both indices to give a more general representation of how it works. But are definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to grab a part of the string from the start then you can use:

```
my_string[:number]
```

if you would like to grab a part of the string from the end:

```
my_string[-number:]
```